# Q: Should suggesting tag synonyms be more accessible?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

**Context**

I saw a question with the tag `k-nn` for K-Nearest Neighbors. I thought it was a typo and that it should be changed to `knn`. To my surprise, the `knn` tag didn't exist and isn't a synonym either.

I thought "fair enough" and wanted to add `knn` as a synonym for `k-nn` so that people like me would find it easier or would not try to create an unnecessary tag.

**Problem**

I was unable to add a synonym for the tag because it requires a score of at least 5 in that tag. I then tried to add a synonym for a tag for which I did meet that requirement. It said that the synonym must have already been used in the site to be added.

**Proposal**

I feel that adding synonyms should be more accessible. The primary goal of tags is to filter questions in an efficient way. The enemies of this are:

- missing tags

> Currently, tags like `knn` or `automated-machine-learning` do not exist. If someone searches for them, they might think they need to add them to the site. Which leads to:

- redundant tags

> If they don't know about `k-nn` and `automl` we will have redundant tags. To fix it, someone will need to point this out, and provide them as synonyms of each other.

I propose that suggesting synonyms should be open to every member (with enough reputation). The reviewing process might need to be stricter but I do believe it would serve the reason tags exist in the first place more efficiently.

Comment: These privilege-based limitations is across the SO network. So, what I suggest is the following: 'If you think you have a valid suggestion for a tag synonym or a change in tag needed, then do go ahead and raise a question/post in meta and anyone with enough rep can go ahead and help you with that, post vetting"

Comment: Didn't know it was SO-wide, thanks. I will do this in the future, hopefully this won't be seen as bad questions on meta

Comment: No question is a bad question on meta :)